# Django - Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<topic>[^/]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and there was a problem. I will be grateful if you help

Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[^/]+)/\Z']

views:

```
def topic(request, topic):
    topic = New_topic.objects.get(id=topic)
    comments = topic.comment_set.order_by('+date')
    context = {'topic':topic, 'comments':comments}
    return render(request, 'topic.html', context)
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = "forum"

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.main, name='main'),
path('<int:topic>/', views.topic, name='topic')
]
```

models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class New_topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Comments(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(New_topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

template:
main.html

```
{% block content %}
{% for list_forum in list %}
<a href="{% url 'forum:topic' topic.id  %}">{{ list_forum }}</a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

topic.html

```
{% block content %}
  {{ topic }}
  {% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment.text|linebreaks }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Is this the view and template you are requesting? You pass `topic` and `comments` to context, but then loop for `list`, which is empty and the whole loop block should get skipped.

Comment: The rendering of the page is handled by topic.html, not main.html

P.S add topic.html

Comment: There is nothing interesting in `topic.html`. The error is caused when you call `{% url %}` in template, or call `reverse()` in view function. Does this `topic.html` inherit from some template that has a `{% url %}` tag?

Comment: It is inherited from base.html which is a link to authorization or registration

Comment: I would say `main.html` is very suspicious based on the info you provide. Just remove that `{% url %}` tag and see if the problem still exists. If it does, continue removing `{% url %}` tags that might cause the problem.

Comment: I fixed it somehow, but I don't know how... I definitely didn't remove anything from the url

Comment: I just reassigned the app url from index to forum

Answer (score 0):

Try `path('<topic>/<int:pk>/', views.topic, name='topic')`

Comment: Did not help. If you call the page via url, for example 127.0.0.1/<number_topic>, then it works

Comment: Try to change `pk` to `topic_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I just reassigned the app url from "index" to "forum"

path('', include('forum.urls')) to change path('forum/', include('forum.urls'))